# Use Socks proxy on Android without rooting in Android 5.1

Tags: applications, google-play-store, rooting, proxy

I have a Socks5 proxy and I need to configure it in my mobile so that all traffic of the apps goes through that proxy. How can I configure Socks5 proxy without rooting the mobile ?

I have seen **'ProxyDroid'** on 'Google Play Store' but it needs the phone to be rooted. Tried Another app **'Drony'** but not able to successfully make the connection. I might be doing something wrong.

Please suggest a solution .

```
Environment 

Android Version  ::   5.1
Mobile           ::   MOTO E  , Samsung J2
```

Answer (score 1):

Drony should work. But not sure if latest SOCKS5 features are supported. Can you try with ccproxy socks5? I'm sure that works with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tutorial a while ago, should still work, though it's only for web traffic:

https://www.devineloper.com/2013/08/28/setup-socks-proxy-android-without-root/

 
From what I've read, you can set a regular proxy in Android connection settings, but it's up to apps to decide if they want to use it. Hence the need to root in order to force all traffic through.