# Proxy server connection

Tags: networking, mobile-network, proxy, ad-hoc-networks

I have got a question.

I am a college student in India, my college provides free wifi throughout the campus . To access the wifi we have to use the proxy server connection , we use apps like psiphon pro to connect. Using this proxy server connection we can access youtube and many other apps but apps like PUBG,netflix etc don't connect to this server and we cant use these.

I just want to know why is that these few apps dont connect to the proxy server while other apps do. I dont have much knowledge about network and proxy servers. Is there any we can use PUBG mobile using college proxy.

I am planning to develop an android application which can allow users to play PUBG mobile using college proxy. Shall I reach out to the PUBG mobile developers , so that they can help out as why is it happening so.

Please tell me what you think about this issue and is there any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is not all traffic captured from my device when routing through proxy?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205015/why-is-not-all-traffic-captured-from-my-device-when-routing-through-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the used proxy server is an HTTP proxy server (also called Web Proxy server). This means effectively that you can only make HTTP connections (which is a TCP based protocol).

Online games require fast responses therefore they usually use UDP or at least TCP. A game that essentially requires a fast reaction rate like PUBG never use HTTP for game data.

Therefore if your proxy server only supports HTTP(S) you can't tunnel UDP traffic through it without loosing the speed advantage of UDP. Hence if you really would finally succeed to tunnel PUBG traffic through your proxy you will most likely pay this by extreme high latency values making it no fun to play.

Hence you may succeed in your "project" but anyhow at the same time loose.

The only chance I see if the used proxy would support the SOCKS-5 protocol. However it seems like [Android can't use this proxy type without third party apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172489/use-socks-proxy-on-android-without-rooting-in-android-5-1) therefore it would be really luck if the used proxy would support this.